# swift linker command failed with exit code 1 Google Maps iOS Util pod install

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoapods, google-maps-ios-utils

My build failed with `swift linker command failed with exit code 1`. The logs specifically say `symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

This happened ever since I tried setting up `Google-Maps-iOS-Utils`.

This is my Podfile. There is a `pre_install` portion because without it, `pod install` will have a `'Pods-Project' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries` error.

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'My App' do
  use_frameworks!

  platform :ios, '11.3'

  # Pods for My App
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' #the new pod that caused issues
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.9'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.5'

  target 'My AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
end
```

This is my Bridging-Header.h

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h
#import <Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h>
#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

Some troubleshooting measures I tried: 
Cleaning Build Folder and Building again;
de-integrating pods and pod installing again.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md

Comment: Add library location in binary search path of Build setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This solution](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md) worked for me. There is no need for this portion in the Podfile as well.

```
pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
end
```

I also had to delete the framework the binary search path in Build Phases.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add library location in binary search path of build setting.